# How to use netperf on specific NIC port?

Tags: linux, networking, network-adapter, tcp, udp

I have two servers, `SERVER` and `CLIENT` and each server has its own onboard 1 GbE ports, and its own NIC with a 10 GbE port. `SERVER` and `CLIENT` are interconnected on both a 1 GbE switch (administrative traffic) and a 10 GbE switch (data traffic).

I want to test the performance of the 10 gigabit connection specifically using `netperf`. How I specify to use the 10 GbE NIC ports instead of the 1 GbE onboard ports for the test?

Right now this is what I'm doing:

```
root@SERVER:~$ netserver
Starting netserver at port 12865
Starting netserver at hostname 0.0.0.0 port 12865 and family AF_UNSPEC

root@CLIENT:~$ netperf -H SERVER -l 15
```

Comment: If `netperf` doesn't support selecting the NIC to test, you could consider changing the metric of the route you want to use.

Comment: I that did help, please comment here and I'll write an answer that hopefully will also help other people.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on "changing the metric of the route you want to use"? I have figured out 50% of how to do this through netperf. On the server side, I assign static IPs to the 10 GbE interfaces as follows: ifconfig eth2 192.168.2.1 and ifconfig eth3 192.168.3.1 and then start separate netserver tasks for each port as follows: netserver -L 192.168.2.1 and netserver -L 192.168.3.1. But I haven't figured out what to do on the client side as any IP address assigned to individual interfaces should be resolved locally to 0.0.0.0 in the TCP/IP stack.